# Error accessing field [private int ...] by reflection for persistent property

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I keep getting the Error message in the File, I do not understand how to fix it and was unable to find a solution.

**This is my model.**

```java
package bbw.ch.lf.model;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableMBeanExport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Day.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Day d")
@Table(name="day")
public class Day {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private String year;

    @Column(name = "entry")
    private String entry;

    public Day() {};

    public Day(String entry, String date) {
        this.date = date;
        this.entry = entry;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(String entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }
}
```

**In my DayController, I have this**

```
//Create Day
    @GetMapping("day/create-day")
    public String redirectToCreateDay(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("day", new Day());
        return "addDay";
    }

    @PostMapping("day/create")
    public String createDay(@ModelAttribute Day day, Model model) {
        dayRepo.createDay(day);
        model.addAttribute("day", dayRepo.fetchAllDays());
        return "days";
    }
```

**And my DayRepository has this**

```java
 EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
 EntityManager em;

    public void setup() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
        em = emFactory.createEntityManager();

    }

    public DayRepository() {
        setup();
    }

public void createDay(Day day) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(day);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
```

Here is the full Error Message

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int bbw.ch.lf.model.Day.id] by reflection for persistent property [bbw.ch.lf.model.Day#id] : bbw.ch.lf.model.Day@60d5b12
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:810)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:788)
> at bbw.ch.lf.Repository.DayRepository.createDay(DayRepository.java:53)
> at bbw.ch.lf.controller.DayController.createDay(DayController.java:46)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int bbw.ch.lf.model.Day.id] by reflection for persistent property [bbw.ch.lf.model.Day#id] : bbw.ch.lf.model.Day@60d5b12
> at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5003)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4703)
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:556)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:803)
> ... 57 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field bbw.ch.lf.model.Day.id to bbw.ch.lf.model.Day
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:594)
> at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:62)
> ... 65 more

Comment: Try to change this `int id` to `Integer id`

Comment: @SternK I still get the same Error message

Comment: Do you have the column `id` in the table `day` ?

Comment: @SternK yes I do

Comment: Try to put all your annotations from fields to the appropriate getters.

Comment: @SternK this gave me a different error which was "Error creating bean with name 'dayController' defined in file"